# sqlite or mysql for large datasets

Tags: mysql, sqlite, r

I am working with large datasets (10s of millions of records, at times, 100s of millions), and want to use a database program that links well with R. I am trying to decide between mysql and sqlite.  The data is static, but there are lot of queries that I need to do.

In this [link to sqlite help](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html), it states that:

"With the default page size of 1024 bytes, an SQLite database is limited in size to 2 terabytes (241 bytes). And even if it could handle larger databases, SQLite stores the entire database in a single disk file and many filesystems limit the maximum size of files to something less than this. So if you are contemplating databases of this magnitude, you would do well to consider using a client/server database engine that spreads its content across multiple disk files, and perhaps across multiple volumes."

I'm not sure what this means.  When I have experimented with mysql and sqlite, it seems that mysql is faster, but I haven't constructed very rigorous speed tests.  I'm wondering if mysql is a better choice for me than sqlite due to the size of my dataset.  The description above seems to suggest that this might be the case, but my data is no where near 2TB.

I'd appreciate any insights into understanding this constraint of maximum file size from the filesystem and how this could affect speed for indexing tables and running queries.  This could really help me in my decision of which database to use for my analysis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SQLite database engine stores the entire database into a single file. This may not be very efficient for incredibly large files (SQLite's limit is 2TB, as you've found in the help). In addition, SQLite is limited to one user at a time. If your application is web based or might end up being multi-threaded (like an `AsyncTask` on Android), mysql is probably the way to go.

Personally, since you've done tests and mysql is faster, I'd just go with mysql. It will be more scalable going into the future and will allow you to do more.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm not sure what this means. When I have experimented with mysql and sqlite, it seems that mysql is faster, but I haven't constructed very rigorous speed tests.

The short short version is:

1. If your app needs to fit on a phone or some other embedded system, use SQLite. That's what it was designed for.
2. If your app might ever need more than ***one*** concurrent connection, do not use SQLite. Use PostgreSQL, MySQL with InnoDB, etc.

Comment: The OP mentions that the data are static, which suggests that perhaps only `SELECT`'s will be run, in which case SQLite may be able to handle concurrent connections fairly well?

Comment: Yeah, but it's way too many rows for SQLite imho. It would result in too enormous a file.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that (in R, at least), that SQLite is awesome for *ad hoc* analysis. With the `RSQLite` or `sqldf` packages it is really easy to load data and get started. But for data that you'll use over and over again, it seems to me that MySQL (or SQL Server) is the way to go because it offers a lot more features in terms of modifying your database (e.g., adding or changing keys).

Answer (score 1):

SQL if you are mainly using this as a web service.
SQLite, if you want it to able to function offline.

SQLite generally is much much faster, as majority (or ALL) of data/indexes will be cached in memory. However, in the case of SQLite. If the data is split up across multiple tables, or even multiple SQLite database files, from my experience so far. For even millions of records (i yet to have 100's of millions though), it is far more effective then SQL (compensate the latency / etc). However that is when the records are split apart in differant tables, and queries are specific to such tables (dun query all tables).

An example would be a item database used in a simple game. While this may not sound much, a UID would be issued for even variations. So the generator soon quickly work out to more then a million set of 'stats' with variations. However this was mainly due to each 1000 sets of records being split among different tables. (as we mainly pull records via its UID). Though the performance of splitting was not properly measured. We were getting queries that were easily 10 times faster then SQL (Mainly due to network latency).

Amusingly though, we ended up reducing the database to a few 1000 entries, having item [pre-fix] / [suf-fix] determine the variations. (Like diablo, only that it was hidden). Which proved to be much faster at the end of the day.

On a side note though, my case was mainly due to the queries being lined up one after another (waiting for the one before it). If however, you are able to do multiple connections / queries to the server at the same time. The performance drop in SQL, is more then compensated, from your client side. Assuming this queries do not branch / interact with one another (eg. if got result query this, else that)