# Best way to join two large datasets in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management

I'm downloading two datasets from two different databases that need to be joined. Each of them separately is around 500MB when I store them as CSV. Separately the fit into the memory but when I load both I sometimes get a memory error. I definitely get into trouble when I try to merge them with pandas.

What is the best way to do an outer join on them so that I don't get a memory error? I don't have any database servers at hand but I can install any kind of open source software on my computer if that helps. Ideally I would still like to solve it in pandas only but not sure if this is possible at all.

To clarify: with merging I mean an outer join. Each table has two row: product and version. I want to check which products and versions are in the left table only, right table only and both tables. That I do with a

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,left_on=['product','version'],right_on=['product','version'], how='outer')
```

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Please specify in more detail what you expect this program to do and on what fields the join is supposed to work. In the best case, you could just merge the two CSV files together (line by line). Also, if you could post the code that results in the memory error, this would help a lot.

Comment: I have added more details to the original question

Answer (score 36):

This seems like a task that [`dask`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/index.html) was designed for.  Essentially, `dask` can do `pandas` operations out-of-core, so you can work with datasets that don't fit into memory.  The `dask.dataframe` API is a subset of the `pandas` API, so there shouldn't be much of a learning curve.  See the [Dask DataFrame Overview](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) page for some additional DataFrame specific details.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Read in the csv files.
df1 = dd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = dd.read_csv('file2.csv')

# Merge the csv files.
df = dd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['product','version'])

# Write the output.
df.to_csv('file3.csv', index=False)
```

Assuming that `'product'` and `'version'` are the only columns, it may be more efficient to replace the `merge` with:

```
df = dd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates()
```

I'm not entirely sure if that will be better, but apparently merges that aren't done on the index are "slow-ish" in `dask`, so it could be worth a try.

Comment: Great but what if df1 doesn't fit into memory either?

Comment: That's the entire point of `dask`.  It does manipulations out-of-core, so you can work with data that doesn't fit into memory. It essentially extends the size of convenient datasets from “fits in memory” to “fits on disk”.

Comment: is there any way to do pivot tables with large dataframes? Dask doesn't seem to offer that functionality

Comment: Dask seems to be very buggy. Even simple merge operations give error messages. Column names contain \r at the end etc. Is there any alternative?

Comment: Dask is under development, it also doesn't support multi-indexes. :(

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use RDBMS like MySQL for that...

So you would need to [load your CSV files into tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11077961/5741205) first.

After that you can perform your checks:

which products and versions are in the left table only

```
SELECT a.product, a.version
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b
ON a.product = b.product AND a.version = b.version
WHERE b.product IS NULL;
```

which products and versions are in the right table only

```
SELECT b.product, b.version
FROM table_a a
RIGHT JOIN table_b b
ON a.product = b.product AND a.version = b.version
WHERE a.product IS NULL;
```

in both

```
SELECT a.product, a.version
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b
ON a.product = b.product AND a.version = b.version;
```

[Configure your MySQL Server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-optimization.html), so that it uses at least 2GB of RAM

You may also want to use MyISAM engine for your tables, in this case check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/myisam-key-cache.html)

It might work slower compared to Pandas, but you definitely won't have memory issues.

Another possible solutions:

- increase your RAM
- use Apache Spark SQL (distributed DataFrame) on multiple cluster nodes  - it will be much cheaper though to increase your RAM

Comment: Thanks for this. But why can't the OS not extend the RAM with hard disk space?

Comment: Usually it should be possible (at least for Windows and Linux, i've no experience with Mac OS's), but it's extremely ineffective

Comment: I'm using Windows and it clearly does not use my SSD HD as extension

Comment: @nickpick, did you configure your SSD HD as a single source for your pagefile (swap file)? But as i said in the answer - it would be better either to use MySQL or physically increase your RAM

Comment: Ok, what about SQLite?

Comment: @nickpick, you can try it, but it's very poor compared to MySQL, especially when talking about big tables. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316319/sqlite-or-mysql-for-large-datasets) might be interesting for you...