# Join two large files by column in python

Tags: python, pandas, join, dask, chunks

I have 2 files with 38374732 lines in each and size 3.3 G each. I am trying to join them on the first column. For doing so I decided to use pandas with the following code that pulled from Stackoverflow:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import sys
 a = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1],sep='\t',encoding="utf-8-sig")
 b = pd.read_csv(sys.argv[2],sep='\t',encoding="utf-8-sig")
 chunksize = 10 ** 6
 for chunk in a(chunksize=chunksize):
   merged = chunk.merge(b, on='Bin_ID')
   merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False,sep='\t')
```

However I am getting memory error(not surprising). I looked up at the code with chunks for pandas (something like this [How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)), however how do I implement it for two files in a loop and I don't think I can chunk the second file as I need to lookup for column in the whole second file.Is there a way out for this?

Comment: I changed my question, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is already discussed in other posts like the one you mentioned ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37757496/6188901), or [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13059/merging-large-csv-files-in-pandas)).

As it is explained there, I would try to use [dask dataframe](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) to load the data and execute the merge, but depending on your PC you may still not be able to do it.

Minimum working example:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

# Read the CSVs
df1 = dd.read_csv('data1.csv')
df2 = dd.read_csv('data2.csv')

# Merge them
df = dd.merge(df1, df2, on='Bin_ID').compute()

# Save the merged dataframe
df.to_csv('merged.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Eventually you can fire directly `to_parquet()`/`to_csv()` instead of `.compute()`

Comment: `to_csv()` is already called in the example above. `compute()` is necessary if you want to obtain results [in memory](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/user-interfaces.html#laziness-and-computing). If they don't fit in memory then yes, you can save them directly into disk.

Comment: I guess we are saying the same thing. ;)

Comment: How do I install dask dataframe in pipfile?