# MemoryError when perforimg a pandas inner merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two files using pandas, one of which is very large(6gb). Whenever I try it, I get a Memory error, as my RAM(8gb) is probably too small to handle it. Any ideas on how I could fix this?
my code is:

```
 import pandas as pd
broad_matched = pd.read_csv("FILE A", delim_whitespace=True)
broad_matched2 = broad_matched[~(broad_matched['P'] >= 0.05)]
SNPs= pd.read_csv("FILE B", 
                  sep='\t', 
                 names=["#CHROM","POS1","POS", "rsID","E","F"])
broad_matched2=broad_matched2.drop(columns=['LOG.OR._SE','ID','REF','ALT','ERRCODE','Z_STAT','OR','OBS_CT','TEST','FIRTH.','A1','#CHROM'])
Table1=pd.merge(broad_matched2,SNPs,on='POS',how='inner').dropna()
Table1.to_csv(r'D:/Table1', index = False)
```

Comment: pandas hold files in RAM, so with pandas you cannot with 8GB, you need more ram. try . do it online, using google codelab, it gives you 25gb ram or any other online notebook

Comment: Try to use Dask library

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101772/join-two-large-files-by-column-in-python). The solution involves using dask dataframes.