# Efficient way to merge multiple large DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, out-of-memory

Suppose I have 4 small DataFrames

`df1`, `df2`, `df3` and `df4`

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 10], ['a', 2, 20], ['b', 1, 4], ['c', 1, 2], ['e', 2, 10]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 15], ['a', 2, 20], ['c', 1, 2]])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['d', 1, 10], ['e', 2, 20], ['f', 1, 1]])  
df4 = pd.DataFrame([['d', 1, 10], ['e', 2, 20], ['f', 1, 15]])   


df1.columns = ['name', 'id', 'price']
df2.columns = ['name', 'id', 'price']
df3.columns = ['name', 'id', 'price']    
df4.columns = ['name', 'id', 'price']   

df1 = df1.rename(columns={'price':'pricepart1'})
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'price':'pricepart2'})
df3 = df3.rename(columns={'price':'pricepart3'})
df4 = df4.rename(columns={'price':'pricepart4'})
```

Create above are the 4 DataFrames, what I would like is in the code below.

```
# Merge dataframes
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=['name', 'id'], right_on=['name', 'id'], how='outer')
df = pd.merge(df , df3, left_on=['name', 'id'], right_on=['name', 'id'], how='outer')
df = pd.merge(df , df4, left_on=['name', 'id'], right_on=['name', 'id'], how='outer')

# Fill na values with 'missing'
df = df.fillna('missing')
```

So I have achieved this for 4 DataFrames that don't have many rows and columns.

**Basically, I want to extend the above outer merge solution to MULTIPLE (48) DataFrames of size 62245 X 3:**

So I came up with this solution by building from another StackOverflow answer that used a lambda reduce:

```
from functools import reduce
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dfList = []

#To create the 48 DataFrames of size 62245 X 3
for i in range(0, 49):

    dfList.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(62245, 3)), columns=['name',  'id',  'pricepart' + str(i + 1)]))


#The solution I came up with to extend the solution to more than 3 DataFrames
df_merged = reduce(lambda  left, right: pd.merge(left, right, left_on=['name', 'id'], right_on=['name', 'id'], how='outer'), dfList).fillna('missing')
```

This is causing a `MemoryError`.

I do not know what to do to stop the kernel from dying.. I've been stuck on this for two days.. Some code for the EXACT merge operation that I have performed that does not cause the `MemoryError` or something that gives you the same result, would be really appreciated.

Also, the 3 columns in the main DataFrame (NOT the reproducible 48 DataFrames in the example) are of type `int64`, `int64` and `float64` and I'd prefer them to stay that way because of the integer and float that it represents.

EDIT:

Instead of iteratively trying to run the merge operations or using the reduce lambda functions, I have done it in groups of 2! Also, I've changed the datatype of some columns, some did not need to be `float64`. So I brought it down to `float16`. It gets very far but still ends up throwing a `MemoryError`.

```
intermediatedfList = dfList    

tempdfList = []    

#Until I merge all the 48 frames two at a time, till it becomes size 2
while(len(intermediatedfList) != 2):

    #If there are even number of DataFrames
    if len(intermediatedfList)%2 == 0:

        #Go in steps of two
        for i in range(0, len(intermediatedfList), 2):

            #Merge DataFrame in index i, i + 1
            df1 = pd.merge(intermediatedfList[i], intermediatedfList[i + 1], left_on=['name',  'id'], right_on=['name',  'id'], how='outer')
            print(df1.info(memory_usage='deep'))

            #Append it to this list
            tempdfList.append(df1)

        #After DataFrames in intermediatedfList merging it two at a time using an auxillary list tempdfList, 
        #Set intermediatedfList to be equal to tempdfList, so it can continue the while loop. 
        intermediatedfList = tempdfList 

    else:

        #If there are odd number of DataFrames, keep the first DataFrame out

        tempdfList = [intermediatedfList[0]]

        #Go in steps of two starting from 1 instead of 0
        for i in range(1, len(intermediatedfList), 2):

            #Merge DataFrame in index i, i + 1
            df1 = pd.merge(intermediatedfList[i], intermediatedfList[i + 1], left_on=['name',  'id'], right_on=['name',  'id'], how='outer')
            print(df1.info(memory_usage='deep'))
            tempdfList.append(df1)

        #After DataFrames in intermediatedfList merging it two at a time using an auxillary list tempdfList, 
        #Set intermediatedfList to be equal to tempdfList, so it can continue the while loop. 
        intermediatedfList = tempdfList
```

Is there any way I can optimize my code to avoid `MemoryError`, I've even used AWS 192GB RAM (I now owe them 7$ which I could've given one of yall), that gets farther than what I've gotten, and it still throws `MemoryError` after reducing a list of 28 DataFrames to 4..

Comment: @coldspeed if I'm not wrong the concat in your answer should be doing the outer merge correctly, as indeed the output of your answer shows - in the example by Abhishek, you get the same answer as he does, and not the empty DataFrame you'd get with 'inner'.

Comment: @MarcoSpinaci is that so? ...huh, interesting, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may get some benefit from performing index-aligned concatenation using `pd.concat`. This should hopefully be faster and more memory efficient than an outer merge as well.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, ...]
for df in df_list:
    df.set_index(['name', 'id'], inplace=True)

df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1) # join='inner'
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Alternatively, you can replace the `concat` (second step) by an iterative `join`:

```
from functools import reduce
df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.join(y), df_list)
```

This may or may not be better than the `merge`.

Comment: concat is definitely way faster than append or merge.

Comment: ANy idea how can i overcome this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58077949/dataframe-merge-gives-process-finished-with-exit-code-137-interrupted-by-signa?

Answer (score 5):

Seems like part of what dask dataframes were designed to do (out of memory ops with dataframes).  See 
[Best way to join two large datasets in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756991/best-way-to-join-two-large-datasets-in-pandas) for example code.  Sorry not copying and pasting but don't want to seem like I am trying to take credit from answerer in linked entry.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a simple `for` loop. The only memory optimization I have applied is downcasting to most optimal `int` type via `pd.to_numeric`.

I am also using a dictionary to store dataframes. This is good practice for holding a variable number of variables.

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = {}
dfs[1] = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 10], ['a', 2, 20], ['b', 1, 4], ['c', 1, 2], ['e', 2, 10]])
dfs[2] = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 15], ['a', 2, 20], ['c', 1, 2]])
dfs[3] = pd.DataFrame([['d', 1, 10], ['e', 2, 20], ['f', 1, 1]])  
dfs[4] = pd.DataFrame([['d', 1, 10], ['e', 2, 20], ['f', 1, 15]])   

df = dfs[1].copy()

for i in range(2, max(dfs)+1):
    df = pd.merge(df, dfs[i].rename(columns={2: i+1}),
                  left_on=[0, 1], right_on=[0, 1], how='outer').fillna(-1)
    df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')

print(df)

   0  1   2   3   4   5
0  a  1  10  15  -1  -1
1  a  2  20  20  -1  -1
2  b  1   4  -1  -1  -1
3  c  1   2   2  -1  -1
4  e  2  10  -1  20  20
5  d  1  -1  -1  10  10
6  f  1  -1  -1   1  15
```

You should not, as a rule, combine strings such as "missing" with numeric types, as this will turn your entire series into `object` type series. Here we use `-1`, but you may wish to use `NaN` with `float` dtype instead.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have 48 dfs with 3 columns each - name, id, and different column for every df.

You don`t must to use merge....

Instead, if you concat all the dfs

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4])
```

You will recieve:

```
Out[3]: 
   id name  pricepart1  pricepart2  pricepart3  pricepart4
0   1    a        10.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
1   2    a        20.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
2   1    b         4.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
3   1    c         2.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
4   2    e        10.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
0   1    a         NaN        15.0         NaN         NaN
1   2    a         NaN        20.0         NaN         NaN
2   1    c         NaN         2.0         NaN         NaN
0   1    d         NaN         NaN        10.0         NaN
1   2    e         NaN         NaN        20.0         NaN
2   1    f         NaN         NaN         1.0         NaN
0   1    d         NaN         NaN         NaN        10.0
1   2    e         NaN         NaN         NaN        20.0
2   1    f         NaN         NaN         NaN        15.0
```

Now you can group by name and id and take the sum:

```
df.groupby(['name','id']).sum().fillna('missing').reset_index()
```

If you will try it with the 48 dfs you will see it solves the MemoryError:

```
dfList = []
#To create the 48 DataFrames of size 62245 X 3
for i in range(0, 49):
    dfList.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(62245, 3)), columns=['name',  'id',  'pricepart' + str(i + 1)]))

df = pd.concat(dfList)
df.groupby(['name','id']).sum().fillna('missing').reset_index()
```

Comment: This is identical to my answer and worse because it replicates the name and ID column. -1

Comment: Also, nothing was said about a groupby being needed here.

Comment: Maybe I wasn`t clear enough. I edited the answer. Did you try to run it with the 48 dfs? It solves the MemoryError...

Comment: Just because it worked for you doesn't mean it'd work for OP. And that wasn't the _point_ of my last comment, I've already mentioned a `concat` solution before you did. So if your answer fixes the memory error, so will mine.