# Is it possible to avoid creating duplicates while using pd.merge?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I have 2 dataFrames to merge. One is df = [19894 rows x 4 columns] (so pretty big) and another one is airports = [2k rows x 4 columns].
When I pd.merge them

```
df = pd.merge(df, airport, on=['origin'], how='inner')
```

I get df that is [258031994 rows x 6 columns] !!!
however when I df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True) it goes back to being 19894 rows which is fine and they indeed are merged.

My issue is that I have 12 months of data a year and 3 years worth of data to analyse and I get error "Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)"
(my second months creates DataFrame of 340m x 6 columns...)

Is there a way to merge/join data frames without creating a multimillion monstrosity?

Comment: Try [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50886269/efficient-way-to-merge-multiple-large-dataframes).

Comment: if you mean the pd.concat then I have tried it but get errors :(