# How to filter a pandas DataFrame according to a list of tuples?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, tuples

How to filter dataframe from a set of tuples, so that the pairing is the same? I need a more elegant way of writing. Im trying not to use merge because it will make it less efficient.

So I have a list of tuple called tup_list: 
`[('118', '35'), ('35', '35'), ('118', '202')`
Assuming the first element in each tuple is A, and the second is B, I am trying to filter my dataframe according to this tup_list, where the pairing needs to be the same.

Original dataframe:

```
A   B
118 35
118 40
35  202
118 1
35  35
```

After filtering according to the tup_list, the new dataframe should be:

```
A   B
118 35
35  35
```

Only exact pairings should be returned.

Currently Im using `df= df.merge(tup_list, on=['A','B'], how='inner'). But is not very efficient as my actual data is larger.`

Please advise on more efficient way of writing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37757496/7053679 see this answer and use `dask` library

Comment: How much larger?

Comment: Its around 800mb

Comment: Still fitting in RAM I guess, so this should be fast

Answer (score 8):

use boolean indexing:

```
tup_list = [(118, 35), (35, 35), (118, 202)]
df[pd.Series(list(zip(df['A'], df['B']))).isin(tup_list)]

    A   B
0   118 35
4   35  35
```

`list(zip(df['A'], df['B']))` turns your two columns into a list of tuples:

```
[(118, 35), (118, 40), (35, 202), (118, 1), (35, 35)]
```

which you are turning into a series and using `isin` to return a boolean:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Which can be used in boolean indexing

Comment: weirdly, this doesnt produce the result i want. Out of the 5 disctinct pairs of values it was supposed to show, it only showed 2 distinct pairs of values.

Comment: @R_abcdefg it doesn't produce the result you want on your actual dataset?

Comment: it didnt return the result i wanted. :(

Comment: are you sure your `tup_list` is correct: not strings but actual `ints` or your data frame contains `ints` and not strings. What is the `dtype` of df['A'] and df['B']?

Comment: My tuplist are strings. and the dtype of df['A'] and df['B'] are both object

Comment: @R_abcdefg I would make sure that the values in your data frame are the same type as the values in you tuple list: Compare strings with strings.

Comment: Is there anyway to check the element type in tuple? Because the column type in my datatframe is non-null object type. but Im not sure how to hceck object type for the element in tuple.

Answer (score 4):

With your `tup_list` and dataframe named `df` here is a one liner for the requested output:

```
df[[x in tup_list for x in list(zip(df.A,df.B))]]
```

Comment: I believe you don't need to use ```list``` as ```zip``` is already an iterable. You can change your code to ```df[[x in tup_list for x in zip(df.A,df.B)]]```

Answer (score 0):

With `pandas.DataFrame.query` you can also filter your dataframe according to your list of tuples

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

f = [('118', '35'), ('35', '35'), ('118', '202')]
idxs = [df.query('A=='+ t[0] + ' and B==' + t[1]).index.values for t in f]
idxs = np.concatenate(idxs).ravel().tolist()
df2 = df.iloc[idxs,:]
print(df2)
#      A   B
# 0  118  35
# 4   35  35
```