# Pandas: best way to remove rows where columns match any set of values in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns, A and B. I also have a list of tuples. I want to remove any rows where it matches any of the tuples in the list. For example:

**Input:**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 2 |
| A | 3 |

```
[(A,1),(C,4),(A,3)]
```

**Output:**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| B | 2 |

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you think it didn't work. See ["What Have You Tried?"](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) for an excellent article that you may be interested to read. Thanks.

Comment: "I have two columns, A and B." *What does this mean*? Is this a Pandas Dataframe with two columns with those names? The best way to explain what the values in your program is, is to *show the code that sets them*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` + list comprehension:

```
tuples = [('A', 1), ('C', 4), ('A', 3)]
new_df = df[[x not in tuples for x in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]]
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   A  B
1  A  4
2  B  2
```

Comment: Generating that mask takes O(n*m) time in this solution. Simply hashing the tuple list beforehand makes it O(n+m) instead.

Comment: Yes @Antonion, piterbarg's solution is the best, in my opinion. I actually meant to do it, but I was busy at the time and not much of my brain was devoted to this question... :)

Answer (score 1):

Use zip + pandas series to do without for loop (should be faster)
Note: Based upon [How to filter a pandas DataFrame according to a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880934/how-to-filter-a-pandas-dataframe-according-to-a-list-of-tuples)

```
tuples = [('A',1),('C',4),('A',3)]
new_df = df[~pd.Series(list(zip(df['A'], df['B']))).isin(tuples)] # no for loop
>>> new_df
    A   B
1   A   4
2   B   2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do here is to throw all the "blacklisted" tuples into a set (i.e. hash them) and perform a membership test on each row in your list. The membership test will take constant time & the overall time complexity of this algorithm will be O(n + m), with n being the number of items in your list and m being the number of items in your blacklist.

```
def solve(arr, blacklist):
    S = set(blacklist)
    result = [None] * len(arr)
    idx = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] not in S:
           result[idx] = arr[i]
           idx += 1
    return result[:idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

A "pure" pandas solution (whatever that means):

```
df[~df.set_index(['A','B']).index.isin(tuples)]
```

output

```
    A   B
1   A   4
2   B   2
```