# Dask Dataframe Effecient Row Pair Generator?

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

What exactly I want to achieve in terms of input output is a cross - join

Input Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'val'], data = [['a1', 23],['a2', 29], ['a3', 39]])
print(df)
```

```
    A  val
0  a1   23
1  a2   29
2  a3   39
```

Output Example:

```
df['key'] = 1
df.merge(df, how = "outer", on ="key")
```

```
  A_x  val_x  key A_y  val_y
0  a1     23    1  a1     23
1  a1     23    1  a2     29
2  a1     23    1  a3     39
3  a2     29    1  a1     23
4  a2     29    1  a2     29
5  a2     29    1  a3     39
6  a3     39    1  a1     23
7  a3     39    1  a2     29
8  a3     39    1  a3     39
```

How I achieve this for a large dataset with Dask ?

I am interested in getting all row pair combinations of a Dask Dataframe (Similar to a Cartesian Product) to further calculate inter row metrics like distance etc.But I always get a memory error when using Dask Distributed locally, I provided a toy example of what I am trying to achieve.

I am new to dask so I just want to know is this even possible locally ? What should be my ideal paritions size ? What is a better way to get row pairs using dask?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()
client
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = list(range(50)), data =  np.random.rand(10000,50))
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)  # rather than here
ddf = ddf.assign(key = 0)
ddf = dd.merge(ddf, ddf, suffixes=('', '_ch'), on='key', 
npartitions = 10000, how = 'outer')
ddf['0'].mean().compute()
```

I get the following error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 37.3 GiB for an 
array with shape (100000000, 50) and data type float64
```

Local Cluster Details

```
Scheduler: tcp://127.0.0.1:52435
Dashboard: http://127.0.0.1:8787/status
Cluster
Workers: 4
Cores: 12
Memory: 34.10 GB
```

[[image: Task Stream Snapshot1]]

Comment: Do you mind to add the output you are looking for? This doesn't seems to me an efficient approach.

Comment: @rpanai edited the question for a sample input output

Comment: Every chunk and every function using multiple chunks need to fit into memory. Try reducing the numbers of workers (increase the available memory per worker) and try to increase the number of chunks.

Answer (score 0):

A full outer product is likely to generate a very large dataset.  Let's say that each of your intermediate pandas dataframes has only a million rows.  A cross product of that dataframe with itself would hold one trillion rows, and so would probably blow out memory on that machine.

I suspect that you actually want to do something else, and that this is a step in that direction.  I recommend trying to find another path to what you want.  For example, if you want correlation, maybe try out the `corr` method.