How do I avoid 'Unable to allocate 464. GiB' when merging 2 very large dataframes in pandas
So basically I'm merging 2 very large dataframes on a column with an inner join using the .merge() method. I've seen people suggest to remove blank values from the column, however there are none, and blanks elsewhere are vital for the analysis of the data.
I can complete the merge by using the .head() method, however I don't get across the full picture of the data doing so.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756991/best-way-to-join-two-large-datasets-in-pandas The answer in that post suggests to use dask, which was purpose-built for very large dataframes

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
